# Какой анимацией Вы пользуетесь?

Tags: анимация, javascript, css

Выдалось свободное время и я задумался о том, что будет в скором времени, когда я дочитаю материалы о js, css, html..

И тут меня вдруг осенило, что я не знаю какую библиотеку для анимации мне использовать. В гугле их даже больше чем много и наверняка они все почти одинаковые, но все же.
Расскажите, какой анимацией Вы пользуетесь и почему?
Если покажется, что вопрос размытый, то добавлю конкретики -

1. Производительность.
2. Функциональность.
3. Удобство в работе.
4. На какой основе распространяется ( платная, бесплатная, условно бесплатная ( и вот если условно, то на каком моменте заканчивается условность бесплатности ) ).
5. Возможно, что-то ещё о чем я не догадываюсь.

И отдельным пунктом хочется спросить о TweenLite-TweenMax - как у неё дела обстоят с производительность  и какая у неё лицензия?

Comment: вы же с angular заморачивались... у него есть angular-animate

Comment: нет не плохо, 

http://plnkr.co/edit/dRh7YFdTvhii5njNBcfA?p=preview

еще можно использовать библиотеку animate.css

а зачем вам сторонняя анимация когда ее angular поддерживает ?

Comment: я наверное что-то не понимаю, но может Вы объясните - в angular же нет готовой анимации смены альфы-исчезновения, изменения цвета, безье? Или здесь принцип работы этой анимации не такой как у TweenLite? Я просто сразу скажу, что с TweenLite я давно знаком и как-то даже пробовал использовать js версию и проблем с пониманием у меня не было. А вот сейчас Вы говорите и я не понимаю, объясните если не сложно. И чтобы Вы до конца меня поняли скажу вот что - я начал учить js не только из-за сайтов, но и с учетом игр. Сейчас допишу..

Comment: там принцип такой - 1е css анимация, там все просто, на время смены данных элементу присваивается класс, 2й способ - через js, все нормально описано здесь: http://angular.ru/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate

с точки зрения игр, я думаю вам нужен игровой движок, возможно поверх angular, в игровых движках я не шарю, думаю это обычно что-то с canvas и svg

поведение анимации в angular зависит от реализации, вы посмотрите мой пример, там как раз все исчезает и прочее. для облегчения css анимации есть набор animate.css

---
а что за совместимость ? "bower install es5-shim --save-dev" не подойдет ?

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо! Буду читать. И у меня ещё один маленький вопрос - Вы знаете, как настроить совместимость angulare с ie7? Если да, то я новую тему создам, а если нет, то не буду, потому-что врят ли кто-то ответит.

Comment: @shatal


**Angular** или **AngularJS**
---

*никак не angulare!*

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15920889/815386

Comment: Не первый раз пишу с "е" на конце, сам уже замечал. Не получается у меня с совместимостью... Может посмотрите и найдете ошибку http://hashcode.ru/questions/331933/js-cовместимость-angular-с-ie-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Анимации" тоже бывают разных уровней сложности и то, что можно сделать с помощью одной библиотеки, не всегда бывает реализуемо в другой. Вот вам простой пример: [простейшая анимация](http://jsfiddle.net/T5HTd/) с помощью библиотеки jQuery и для сравнения - анимация с помощью библиотеки [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) или библиотеки [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/examples/). Ясное дело, что если мне нужно всего лишь попинать квадратик по экрану, то я не буду прибегать к последним двум, а выберу jQuery или, что более вероятно, вообще напишу на чистом JS. Поэтому, выбор библиотеки, зависит от поставленной задачи. В этой же связи, рассматривать или сравнивать производительность, функционал и прочее - уже теряет смысл. Если мне "кровь из носу" нужно будет что-то на подобии "рыбки", как в демо у Processing.js, то я не буду особо задумываться над производительностью или лицензией. А в случае простых анимаций (*это лично моё предпочтение*), использую или чистый JS, или библиотеку jQuery.

Comment: @Deonis: Спасибо! Честно сказать мне такой ответ кажется странным!) Как это "не думать о производительности" и "лицензии"?))) Я конечно не знаю, как в сайтостроительстве, но неужели все настолько пофигу, что я могу использовать платную анимацию, платные движки для сайтов и модули - бесплатно и при этом ещё и продавать их?)

Comment: @shatal обычно платные движки позволяют по лицензии разрабатывать ни кому ни чего не платя (я контактировал с highcharts например на эту тему в свое время, буквально они сказали - если взлетит присылайте отчисления, мы вам скидку сделаем ещё) если же у вас успешный продукт, базирующийся на чьем-то движке который заметен, то почему бы не заплатить ? причем это касается как и коммерческих движков так и опенсорсных.